# ¿Cómo puedo iterar un array que recibo para una consulta a una api?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

tengo un método que recibe como parámetro un array.
Necesito iterar ese array para coger posición por posición y así conseguir los datos de cada url por una llamada a la API.

Tengo lo siguiente:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

url es el array que recibo, y ese array contiene urls para llamar a la API:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cada url tiene estos datos y necesito mostrarlos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: usas un for.. cual es el problema?? probaste algo?

Comment: Como lo hago?, edito para que veas

Comment: Editado, ya lo subí

Comment: si url es un array... url[i] no tiene lo que queres?

Comment: es que cada url tiene un dato que debo sacar

Comment: He vuelto a editar

Comment: Y entonces? cual es el problema?